# Android Dynamic Delivery using React native

Tags: android, react-native, dynamic-delivery

I have read about android [**Dynamic Delivery**](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/dynamic-delivery) using Android App Bundles to generate and serve optimized APKs for each user’s device configuration, so users download only the code and resources they need to run your app.

> I have created an application using [**react-native**.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) How can we enable the dynamic delivery based on the feature which is required by the user as **feature delivery**.

For example application has two features like Feature-A and Feature-B which is not required for all. So users will download the base APK from the Google Play store and later users will download the feature APK of their requirement or subscription.

Comment: Is this related to your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57252070/dynamically-compiling-and-running-a-react-native-app-inside-another

Comment: Yes, can we do it using android split apk and dynamic delivery concepts with the use of codepush.

Comment: Why do you want to enable dynamic delivery for a react native app when you have code push ? If its a Pure native app, then it makes lot of case for a dynamic delivery feature.

Comment: This question makes sense if **Feature-B** has native SDK integration. Any suggestions is appreciated.